# Submit two unrelated forms rendered on the same page

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to embed two forms ( the data is on 2 unrelated entities) on the same page and submit the form with only one submit button?

The idea is to validate both submitted forms in only one controller Action.

**Entity1** and **Entity2** have absolutely nothing in common.

```
                                  |--------------------------
                                  |    Form 1 (Entity 1)    |
                                  |--------------------------
 ---------------                  |
 |  Main Form  |------------------
 ---------------                  |
                                  |--------------------------
                                  |    Form 2 (Entity 2)    |
                                  |--------------------------
```

Does anyone has any idea if this is possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. Something like this should work:

```
$entity1 = new Entity1();
$entity2 = new Entity2();

$form = $this->createMainForm();

$form->setData(array(
    'entity1' => $entity1,
    'entity2' => $entity2,
));

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // $entity1 and $entity2 should contain the post data
        // and can be persisted or whatever it is you want to do
        // ...
```

You could also create a Model which contains both entities and create a form for it. Using `$mainEntity->getEntity1();` to retreive the capsulated entity.

Comment: Thanks so much @mahok! I was wondering how would the form type look like in  $this->createMainForm? Because it embeds two different type on 2 different entities...

Comment: You just have to add both entities like this: `$builder->add('entity1', 'entity', array('class' => ...)` in the MainFormType.

Comment: But that's an entity field type...it will display a choice list of all the objects saved in Entity1...and that's not exactly what I am after actually. What I'm trying to do is display a form for entity1 and display a form for entity2 at the same time, and not the list of objects saved in entity1 as well as the list of objects saved in entity2. Anyway, your idea of creating a model seem to be the way to go. I am giving this a try, and will accept your answer accordingly :) Thanks so much @mahok. Great answer that is very likely guiding me towards a working solution :)

Comment: My mistake... It should of course be `$this->builder->add('entity1', new Entity1Type());`. This will embed the form for the entity in the original form.

Comment: Ah great! I'll give this a shot, but that looks definitely right. Awesome @mahok.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 3.20

When you build your FormType, in controller execute route & action like below, use " if ($formRegister->isSubmitted()  && $formRegister->getClickedButton('form2') &&...)"

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/welcome", name="welcome")
     */

    public function welcomeAction(Request $request)
    {



        $uLogin = new User();
        $formLogin = $this->createForm(LoginUserFormType::class, $uLogin);



        $uRegister = new User();
        $formRegister = $this->createForm(UserRegistrationFormType::class, $uRegister);



        $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();




        if ($request->isMethod('post')){

            $formLogin->handleRequest($request);
            $formRegister->handleRequest($request);

            if($formLogin->isSubmitted() && $formLogin->getClickedButton('form1')){


                return $this->redirectToRoute('login_success');
            }

            if ($formRegister->isSubmitted()  && $formRegister->getClickedButton('form2') && $formRegister->isValid() ) {


                $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                    ->encodePassword($uRegister, $uRegister ->getPlainPassword());
                $uRegister ->setPassword($password);

                $uRegister->setRole('ROLE_USER');


                $em = $this ->getDoctrine() ->getManager();
                $em -> persist($uRegister);
                $em -> flush();


                return $this->redirectToRoute('register_success');

            }


        }









        return $this->render(
        'form/welcome.html.twig',
            array(
                'form1' => $formLogin -> createView(),
                'form2' => $formRegister -> createView(),
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         =>  $error,
            )
        );
    }
```

Build your routing, and that is it : -)